# How do I add different inner classes to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, inner-classes

So, I'm building a very basic program based on the Warhammer 40k tabletop game as an extra credit assignment for my Comp Sci class. I get to develop the specs and then I implement the specs. In this game, I have a class Army that has an ArrayList of class Units:

`List<Units> unitsList = new ArrayList<Units>();`

I've created the class Units with innerclasses that contain the different unit types. So, a code snippet from that would be:

```
public class Units 
{
   int strength, toughness, attacks, save, wounds;
   class TroopUnit
   {
      public static final int strength = 3;
      public static final int toughness = 3;
      public static final int attacks = 1;
      public static final int save = 5;

      public int wounds = 1;
   }

   class EliteTroopUnit
   {
      public static final int strength = 3;
      public static final int toughness = 3;
      public static final int attacks = 1;
      public static final int save = 4;

      public int wounds = 1;
   }

}
```

There are more unit types, but I think you can get the idea. I've tried adding these different innerclasses of Units inside the Units ArrayList:

```
public Army(int troopPoints, int eliteTroopPoints, int commandPoints,
     int commandTroopPoints, int fastAttackPoints, int heavyAttackPoints)
{      
   for (int i = 0; i < (troopPoints/TROOP_COST); i++)
      if (troopPoints % TROOP_COST == 0) 
      {
         if (points < MAX_POINTS) 
         {
            unitsList.add(new Units.TroopUnit());
            points += TROOP_COST;
            numUnits++;
         }
      }
   for (int i = 0; i < (eliteTroopPoints/ELITE_TROOP_COST); i++)
      if (eliteTroopPoints % ELITE_TROOP_COST == 0) 
      {
         if (points < MAX_POINTS) 
         {
            unitsList.add(new Units.EliteTroopUnit());
            points += ELITE_TROOP_COST;
            numUnits++;
         }
      }
}
```

However, I run into an issue, because I have to declare and instantiate the ArrayList with a specific type of innerclass in order to add an inner class to it. For example, 
`List<Units.someUnitInnerClass> unitsList = new ArrayList<Units.someUnitInnerClass();`

So, is there a workaround for this problem where I can add any of the innerclasses to the ArrayList? Am I going about this problem incorrectly? If so, what are other alternatives? Thank you!

EDIT: I originally had listed this as "How do I add different subclasses to an ArrayList, but that was a mistake (corrected by Rudi Kershaw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example code you gave, `TroopUnit`and `EliteTroopUnit` are **not** subtypes of `Unit`. They are [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

If you want them to be subclasses of `Unit`, they need to **extend** `Unit`. For example;

```
public class Unit {}
public class TroopUnit extends Unit {}
```

In the example above `TroopUnit` extends (and is therefore a subclass of) `Unit`. From a quick glance, it looks as though you could just add `extends Unit` to the end of your inner class declarations and it should do as you intend.

I hope this helps.

References & Further Reading:

- [Oracle Java Inheritance Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)
- [Oracle Nested Classes Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: You're totally right, I meant inner classes. Let me fix that. Alright, let me try out that solution - thanks.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have worked. I had to change the inner classes to static inner classes in order for me to instantiate the inner classes into the ArrayList. For example,
    static class TroopUnit extends Units
Also, thanks!

Comment: @OmarPatel - No problem, I'm glad I could help. If your problem has been solved don't forget to accept the answer which helped you most by clicking the grey tick next to the answer.

Comment: Alright, will do. I'm currently having some issues with this, but I'll keep working on it before I ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a subclass should extends a class. like this:

```
public class TroopUnit extends Units{}
```

Second of all, answer to your title question, which is irrelevant to your code problem, is that you should get a class above in hierarchy than your object which you are adding to list, and because in java *Object* is parent of all Classes then you can instantiate your List like this:

```
List<Object> unitsList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot I could do that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @OmarPatel But consider to make your code right. Use correct terms of inheritance in your code.